# android intent vs observer

Tags: android, android-intent

I am wondering when I should favour an intent based approach over a classic oberserver design pattern in my Android app.

Would it be wize to use intent's to publish events within one activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition**

Observer maintain a list of dependents to notify a change. On the other side Intent is an abstract description of operation. Which can be received by same or multiple application to perform a task.

**Synchronous VS Asynchronous**

Observer is synchronous as the changes effect right-way. Intent is asynchronous.

**Binding**

Observer bindings are compile time.  On the other side intent bindings are at run time

**Secure**

For internal communication observer is much secure as Intent will broadcast message and anyone can receive the message.

**Intent provide additional functionality over Observer on Android platform**

- Communicating with third party application and processes.
- Receive system notification to perform a task
- Application module reuse by third party app. (Ex taking pic)
- Intent stays around and your app can retrieve data in some later time (Sticky Intent)

*Would it be wise to use intent's to publish events within one activity?*

This will depend on your requirement. Look into your requirement to see which one needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think not because a new intent will usually bring a new activity unless your activity has been declared as single top. Anyway intents do not resemble observers much. A Handler can be a better approximation.